# GCM Notification activity is not getting displayed on 2nd Notification upon 1st notificationActivity Display

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I implemented Android app in Android device, I also have received the notification from the server.But the problem I am facing is, when the receive activity is open for 1st notification data and when I receive the 2nd Notification, on clicking the notification 2nd, it is not replacing the Receive activity with updated notification data.
Please help me on this

The following code is being used:-

```
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    //Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when); //UM
    Log.e(TAG, "Input Extra is...: " + msg);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ResultShowActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("Message",msg);
    //notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );

    int iUniqueId = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() & 0xfffffff);
    int when= (int) System.currentTimeMillis() ;
    //PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, iUniqueId,notificationIntent, 0);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, iUniqueId,notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gcm_cloud)
            .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    //mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    mNotificationManager.notify(when, mBuilder.build());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification sent successfully.");
}
```

Comment: Here is the code I am using for pending Intent:--

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! To get the best out of this website, you may want to be more specific about your issue. Perhaps add the affected code.

In your case though, it looks like the issue is around your PendingIntent flags. Add [FLAG UPDATE CURRENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) to update the extras bundle, if that is what you meant to do.